# The connection "database" doesn't exist Django, CentOS7, NGINX, UWSGI

Tags: python, django

I'm running a CentOS 7.2 server with UWSGI serving my django app. However, after much troubling and config problems I managed to get it to start up. However, it shows the login page, and then 500 errors out. The 500 error is because it can't connect to a table "auth_user". I have a database and I've connected to it using the databases parameter in settings.py, however it is empty. When I run python `manage.py migrate --database="mydatabasename"` it gives me an error that says "django.db.utils.ConnectionDoesNotExist: The connection "databasename" doesn't exist" I've spent the last week looking at it and I can't seem to discover what is happening.

The database exists and if I run "python manage.py shell", then I import MySQLdb, and connect to the database with the exact same parameters (still localhost), it works perfectly fine and it can connect with no issue.

Does any experts know what is happening and why there is not a database connection? I have installed mariadb and then of course the secured setup for mysql. I've created the database and assigned a user/password to it. I can login with the username and password as well via mysql and it works on localhost from my virtual environment.

This is my structure...

```
myapi
  -api
    --admin.py
    --serializers.py
    --urls.py
    --etc
  -myapp
    --settings.py
    --urls.py
    --wsgi.py
  -myvirtualenvironment
  manage.py
  requirements.py
```

Here are my relevant files...

Settings.py

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
SECRET_KEY = 'my secret key'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'api',
    'rest_framework',
)
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
)
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    )
}
ROOT_URLCONF = 'myapp.urls'
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myapp.wsgi.application'

ADMINS = [('my name', 'my email')]
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'myhost'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myuser'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
EMAIL_PORT = myport
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
SERVER_EMAIL = "server email"
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
LOGIN_URL = '/admin/login/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR + '/static/'
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'debug': DEBUG
        },
    },
]

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

if 'DJANGO_PRODUCTION' in os.environ:
    STATIC_URL = '/api/v1' + STATIC_URL
    LOGIN_URL = '/api/v1' + LOGIN_URL
    MEDIA_ROOT = '/var/www/myapi/api_files/'
    MEDIA_URL = '/api_files/'
    CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False
    DEBUG = False

    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME': 'mydatabasename',
            'USER': 'myuser',
            'PASSWORD': 'mypass',
            'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
            'OPTIONS': {
                'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'",
            },   
            'PORT': 'myport',
        }
    }

# CELERY SETTINGS
#REDIS_HOST = 'localhost'
#REDIS_PORT = myport
#REDIS_DB = 0

#BROKER_URL = 'redis://%s:%d/%d' % (REDIS_HOST, REDIS_PORT, REDIS_DB)
#CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://%s:%d/%d' % (REDIS_HOST, REDIS_PORT, REDIS_DB)

X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'DENY'
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = True
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = True
```

And then here is my nginx conf file...

```
location /api/v1/ {
    root /var/www/myroot;
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /api/v1;
    uwsgi_modifier1 30;
    proxy_set_header SCRIPT_NAME /api/v1;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/run/uwsgi/myapp.sock;
    location /api/v1/static {
        alias /var/www/myapp/static;
    }
}
```

And here is my wsgi conf file....

```
import os
import sys
os.environ['HTTPS'] = "on"
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_PRODUCTION", "1")

tempvar= "/var/www/myapp/api"
if not tempvar in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, tempvar)
api = "/var/www/bidjobapi"
if not api in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0,api)

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

And here is my uwsgi file....

```
project = myproject
username = myuser
base = /var/www/myapi
chdir = %(base)/%(project)
home = %(base)/myvenv/
module = wsgi:application
master = true
processes = 5
uid = %(username)
socket = /run/uwsgi/myapp.sock
chown-socket = %(username):nginx
chmod-socket = 664
vacuum = true
uid = %(username)
gid = %(username)
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/%(project).log
```

my manage.py has the following.

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")
```

Does anyone see what the problem is and what is going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `--database` parameter to `migrate` is the name of the connection which you have defined in the settings, not the name of the underlying database. In your example you have only defined the `default`, so you should use that - or indeed miss it out completely, because that is the only one.

Also, you need to ensure that you have set the `DJANGO_PRODUCTION` environment variable before you run that command.

Comment: You are a genius my friend! Thank you so much you're a life saver!!!!
Such a simple change and now it works :)